# Modifying text file using reference value

Tags: python

I have the following reference data like

```
21   1
32   2
45   3
```

and there is a text file (file.txt) contains two or more columns like

```
21  32  45
45  21  32
32  45  21
```

I would like to change file.txt using reference value like

```
1   2   3
3   1   2
2   3   1
```

As you can see the reference file, 21, 32, and 45 equal and match the number 1, 2, and 3, respectively.

I coded based on two for loops and compared two values.

```
with open('ref') as f1, open('file.txt') as f2, open('out.txt', 'w') as f3:

     for lines in f1:
         value1 = lines.split()

         for line in f2:
             if value2 == value1[0]:
                value2 = value1[1]
                line = ' '.join(value2) + '\n'
             f3.write(line)
```

Nothing has been changed. How could this make it possible?

Comment: What is your `value2`?

Comment: Sorry, there was missing just above if value2 == value[0]:    There is value2 = line.split()

Comment: I am sorry, what is the output? And basically what do you want to do?

Comment: Guessing value2 = line.split() ?

Comment: Output is the same as file.txt. Nothing has been changed in out.txt. I would like to output based on comparing the first column in reference file with the file.txt, then all numbers in file.txt need to be changed in the second column of reference file. For example, if 21 in file.txt will be changed 1, because the number 21 in first column of the reference file is matching 1 in the second column of reference file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mydict = {}
with open('ref') as f1:
    for line in f1:
        key, value = line.split()
        mydict[key] = value

with open('file.txt') as f2, open('out.txt', 'w') as f3:
    for l in f2:
        line = l.split()
        newline = ''
        for item in line:
            newline += mydict[item] + " "
        f3.write(newline + "\n")
```

Answer (score 1):

You are NOT comparing it right

```
with open('ref') as f1, open('file.txt') as f2, open('out.txt', 'w') as f3:

 for lines in f1:
     value1 = lines.split()

     for line in f2:
         value2 = line.split() # value2 is a list
         if value2 == value1[0]: # if a list is equals to a value => always false
            value2 = value1[1]
            line = ' '.join(value2) + '\n'
         f3.write(line) # so line is still the original line since the if statement is always false
```

Comment: I do not understand why "always false". As I am understanding in my code, the value1[0] is 21, then if any numbers in value2 equal this number(21), then substitute value2 number by value1[1].

Comment: you don't compare a list to a number, `[1,2,3] == 3` is always false, you should do `3 in [1,2,3]` instead

Answer (score 1):

You need a third loop to iterate over the columns of `file.txt`. Something like

```
for line in f2:
    value2 = line.split()
    for item in value2:
        if item == value1[0]:
            value2 = value1[1]
```

A dict seems a good fit to your problem:

```
#/usr/bin/env python
ref = {}
with open("ref") as file:
    for line in file:
        k, v = line.split()
        ref[k] = v

with open("file.txt") as file, open("res", 'w') as res:
        for line in file:
            for item in line.split():
                res.write("%s\t" % ref[item])
            res.write("\n")
```

Comment: Thank you for the comments about this problem.